# Compare two strings and return true if one string contains all characters of other one

Tags: java, string, compare

I was practicing on lintcode and trying to solve this question

Compare two strings A and B, determine whether A contains all of the characters in B.

The characters in string A and B are all Upper Case letters.

I wrote this code which checks each character of B in A and eliminates found characters from A but somehow it fails the test for the input
A = "ABCD"  and B = "ACC" . It gives output as true when it should be giving false

I don't understand the problem in my code

```
    public class Solution {
/**
 * @param A : A string includes Upper Case letters
 * @param B : A string includes Upper Case letter
 * @return :  if string A contains all of the characters in B return true else return false
 */
public boolean compareStrings(String A, String B) {
    // write your code here
    int aLen = A.length();
    int bLen = B.length();
    if (aLen == 0) {
        return bLen == 0;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<bLen; i++){
        String temp = B.substring(i,i);
        if(A.contains(temp))
            A.replace(temp, "");
        else
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: What should be result for strings `A` and `AA`?

Comment: The main problem is that `A.replace(temp, "");` should be `A = A.replace(temp, "");`. I agree Pshemo that the problem could also be clearer.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I tried that. Still not working

Comment: @Pshemo As far as I have understood the question, for input A, AA the output should be false

Comment: Hint: try printing `temp`.

Comment: @Pshemo I cannot print temp since lintcode considers that as an output and does not reach this particular test case

Comment: Then do it on your machine... Or some on-line IDE like ideone.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only want to get rid of one character from `A` each time. Otherwise it won't be there next time you encounter the same character in `B`.

Try using `replaceFirst` instead of `replace`.

Also you need to assign the result back to `A` using `A = A.replaceFirst(...)`, because otherwise you won't actually change the `String`.

Finally, `B.substring(i,i);` is a string of length `0`, not a string of length `1`. Try `"" + B.charAt(i)` or `B.substring(i, i + 1)` instead.

Here is a complete version that works

```
public static boolean compareStrings(String A, String B) {
    // write your code here
    int aLen = A.length();
    int bLen = B.length();
    if (aLen == 0) {
        return bLen == 0;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<bLen; i++){
        String temp = B.substring(i,i + 1);
        if(A.contains(temp))
            A = A.replaceFirst(temp, "");
        else
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions. No effect whatsoever.

Comment: yes, my original code was this B.substring(i, i + 1)
But it wasn't working

Comment: @SadiqHusainKhan Can you give me an example for which these 3 changes don't work?

Comment: B.substring(i, i + 1)  doesn't work for input : "A", ""
error : index out of bounds

Comment: @SadiqHusainKhan That is incorrect. If `B` is `""` then `bLen` is `0`, so the loop will not even be entered. I think the problem is that the code you posted is not the actual version you are using.

Answer (score 1):

the replace() method of String class will replace every occurrence of the first parameter with the second, try with replaceFirst() instead. Sample implementation

```
    public static boolean compareStrings(String A, String B) {
            boolean isOk = true;

            for (int i = 0;i < B.length();i++) {
                    if (!A.contains(B.charAt(i) + "")) {
                        isOk = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    A = A.replaceFirst(B.charAt(i) + "", ""); 
            }
            return isOk;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response